# (True/False) If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and $J:=f([a,b])$, then $J$ is a closed, bounded interval.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I thought this question was a simple restatement of the extreme value theorem, but I got it wrong.

My attempt:

True. Let $$I:=[a,b]$$
Since $f$ is continuous on $I$, $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0:\forall c\in I,0<\vert x-c\vert<\delta\Rightarrow \vert f(x)-f(c)\vert<\epsilon$

Since $I$ is closed and bounded by $a$ and $b$, by the Extreme Value Theorem, $f$ is bounded on $I$. Since $f$ is bounded, it has a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound. Let $$M=\sup_{x\in I}f(x) \text{ and }m=\inf_{x\in I}f(x)$$
Also by the Extreme Value Theorem, we know $\exists x_M,x_m\in I$ such that $$f(x_M)=M,f(x_m)=m$$
We know $J:=f(I)$. Then $$J=[m,M]$$

Comment: That's a fine proof.

Comment: Why does $J$ contain $(m+M)/2$, for example?

Comment: Since, $f$ is continuous, shouldn't it be $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 : \forall c \in I, |x-c| \delta \implies \dots$ (i.e., it holds also when $x=a$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is incomplete: what the extreme value theorem says is that $m$ and $M$ (minimum and maximum of $f$ over $[a,b]$ exist and so $f(I)\subseteq[m,M]$.

However you can conclude by using the intermediate value theorem.