# If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $J := f([a,b])$, then $J$ is a closed, bounded interval.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $J := f([a,b])$, then $J$ is a closed, bounded interval.

Note this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511858/true-false-if-f-is-continuous-on-a-b-and-j-fa-b-then-j-is-a-c). I'd like to see if my completion of the proof is complete and get more understanding of what is going on exactly.

Let $I:= [a,b]$. Note since $f$ is continuous on a closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$, it follows that $f$ is bounded. In addition, by the Extreme Value Theorem define
$$M = \sup_{x\in I} f(x) \quad \text{ and } \quad m = \inf _{x\in I}f(x).$$
Furthermore there exists $x_M,x_m \in I$ such that
$$f(x_M) = M \quad \text{ and } \quad f(x_m) = m.$$
Let $y_0$ be any point such that $f(x_m) = m < y_0 < M = f(x_M)$. Then by the Intermediate Value Theorem there exists a point $x_0 \in(a,b)$ such that $f(x_0) = y_0$.

Then we see that $J:= f(I) = [m,M]$ is a closed and bounded interval.

Is this how the proof is suppose to conclude?

Notes/Questions:

- It is not clear to me why we need the Intermediate Value Theorem to conclude $J$ is a closed and bounded interval.
- Since $M$ is the maximum value in the interval $[m,M]$ and $m$ is the minimum value in the interval, is that not already enough to conclude that $[m,M]$ is a close and bounded interval?

Comment: The extreme value theorem gives you $m \in J$ and $M \in J$ and for all $j \in J$, $m \leq j \leq M$.  But how does this show you have an *interval*, i.e., that every $j \in \Bbb{R}$ with $m \leq j \leq M$ is in $J$?

Comment: Consider for example $f(x)={}$sign$(x)$ on the closed interval $[-2,2]$. Its extreme values $M=1$ and $m=-1$ exist. However, $f([-2,2])$ is definitely not equal to the closed interval $[m,M]=[-1,1]$, but only to the small subset $\{-1,0,1\}$. Its discontinuity allows this to happen.

Comment: @GregMartin, I did not understand the part that $f([-2,2]) = \{-1,0,1\}$? How did you get this? I guess I don't understand the notation $f([-2,2])$.

Comment: The notation $f(S)$, for any set $S$, means the set of values that the function $f$ actually takes on inputs from the set $S$; in other words, $f(S) = \{ f(x) \colon x\in S \}$. (It might be that you were thinking that $f([a,b])$ is a shorthand for $[f(a),f(b)]$ or something like that.) But yes, making sure that you understand the definition of that piece of notation will probably be at least half the battle for understanding the need for IVT here.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks! I was interpreting the “sign” function as “sine” thus the confusion for me. :(